# Infinite loop during useEffect and Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I don't know why but I have infinite loop when fetching data in Redux operations.

I have an app with Redux and ReactJS.

This is my React component

```
const CustomersTable = (props) => {

    useEffect( () => { 
        props.getAllCustomers()
    }, []);

    return  <Table ...props.customers />
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    customers: state.customers,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getAllCustomers: () => dispatch(getAllCustomers()),
})


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(CustomersTable);
```

This is `getAllInvoices()`

```
const fetchCustomers = async() => {
    /**
     * I fetch only documents with flag delete==false
     */
    const snapshot = await firestore.collection("customers").where('deleted', '==', false).get()

    let data = []
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let d = doc.data();
        d.id_db = doc.id
        //...other
        data.push(d)
    })

    return data
}
export const getAllCustomers = () => 
    async (dispatch) => {
        const customers = await fetchCustomers()
        // I reset state becouse I wont duplicate inovices in tables
        dispatch(actions.reset())

        customers.map(customer => dispatch(
            actions.fetch(customer)
        ))
    }
```

And reducers

```
const customerReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.FETCH_CUSTOMERS:
            return {
                ...state, list: [...state.list, action.item]
            }
        case types.RESET_CUSTOMERS:
            return {
                ...state, list: []
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I expect that reducers RESET_CUSTOMERS and then FETCH_CUSTOMERS done job. But it still working in loop reset->customers.

I thought that is still rendered the component in `useEffect` but I think that hook is writing good.

I tested other reducers which are copy-pase reducers from `Customers` and they work well.

**EDIT 1**
@godsenal, thanks for your reply:

`actions.js`:

```
import types from './types'

const fetch = item => ({
    type: types.FETCH_CUSTOMERS, item
})

const reset = item => ({
    type: types.RESET_CUSTOMERS, item
})

export default {
    fetch,
    reset
}
```

As regards `<Table />` it is AntDesign component (https://ant.design/components/table/). Without that, it looks the same.

**EDIT 2**
It is incredible. I copied all files from modules (customers) and paste into contracts directory. Then I changed all variables, functions, etc from customer to contract. Now it working (only contracts), but customers infinite loop. Maybe something disturbs in outside a structure.

**EDIT 3**
I found in app.js that in `mapStateToProps` I added `customers` to props. After remove (because I don't need it in root component) it began works fine. I suspect that fetch method in `<CustomerTable />` affect the `<App />` component and it render in a loop. I discovered that component isn't still updated in a loop, but its mounts and unmounts in a loop.

But still, I don't understand one thing. In `<App />`, I still have in `mapStateToProps` dispatching invoice from a store (the same case as customers) and in this case, everything works fine.

Comment: I can't find any wrong thing in your code. Could you post `actions` and component that render `Customertable` ?

Comment: @godsenal I edited my first post